# SwiftUI app crashes when new sheet triggered by a tapped notification is shown on top of another sheet

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, ipados

I'm really stuck on this one, so hopefully you guys could help me out.

So my app has a notifications manager class which takes care of notifications and I'm adding a new functionality where users can tap on a notification and it will open the app and automatically show a specific sheet / modal. Here's parts of the code:

```
@MainActor
class SENotificationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    private let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        
    @Published var nextViewID: ReviewViewType?   //Will determine which sheet/view to show
```

This is the test method to trigger notification

```
    func setDailyReminder(at triggerTime: DateComponents, completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) async {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        
        content.title = "Log your daily transactions!"
        content.body = "Just a friendly reminder to log all your transactions for today!"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        content.userInfo = ["nextView": ReviewViewType.dailyReview.id]

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerTime, repeats: true)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: ReminderType.dailyReminder.id, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        //Remove existing notifications first
        notificationCenter.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [ReminderType.dailyReminder.id])

        //Add the new notification request
        do {
            try await notificationCenter.add(request)
            completion(true, nil)
        } catch {
            completion(false, error)
        }
    }
```

When notification shows up, this is the code that intercepts the notification and publishes the nextView value.

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse) async {
        if let value = response.notification.request.content.userInfo["nextView"] as? String {
            nextViewID = ReviewViewType(rawValue: value)
        }
    }
```

I setup a variable notificationManager as @StateObject so it's accessible to child views. Now, on my home view, I setup a .sheet($modalViewType...) modifier to show various views.

To receive the value of the nextView from the notificationManager, I added the following modifier:

```
        .onReceive(notificationManager.$nextViewID) { nextView in
            modalViewType = nil
            
            switch nextView {
            case .dailyReview:
                modalViewType = .showDailyRemindersView
            case .weeklyReview:
                modalViewType = .showWeeklyRemindersView
            default:
                break
            }
        }
```

Once the nextView value is published, it will set the modalViewType to whichever view type and the appropriate sheet will be shown. Here's the code for the sheet modifier for reference:

```
                    .sheet(item: $modalViewType, onDismiss: refreshSummaryCards, content: { sheetAction in
                        //display the sheet
                        switch sheetAction {
                        case .addTransaction(let transactionType):
                            if transactionType == .expense || transactionType == .income {
                                TransactionFormView(transactionType: transactionType, defaultDate: baseDate)
                            } else if transactionType == .moneyTransfer {
                                TransferFormView(defaultDate: baseDate)
                            }
                        case .showDailyRemindersView:
                            DailyReminderDetailsView()
                        case .showWeeklyRemindersView:
                            WeeklyReminderDetailsView()
                        default:
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                    })
```

Now here's the problem I am encountering:

When I already have another sheet open i.e. TransactionFormView, then app goes to the background, notification is triggered, user taps on the notification, the app opens back up, the TransactionFormView sheet is hidden, and then the DailyRemindersDetailsView is shown, but the app crashes with an error

> "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present
> modally a view controller...that is already being presented by..."

Is there a better way of managing sheets? The sheets that are triggered by the notification are placed in my HomeView. Is that where it's supposed to be? Because my app has a lot of views. I wonder if that's the right place to put it in?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You can only present one sheet from a single view. You can't add a new sheet, from the same view that your current sheet is from. If your plan is to have a sheet on a sheet, you need to present the second sheet from the first sheet, not the original view.